# how to write java program to acquire admin permission

Tags: java

I want to write a java program which will ask for admin permission (admin username and admin password). If I insert the correct information then i will receive an welcome message.

how to write java program to acquire admin permission.

I am using Fedora 10 linux.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: @sunil: are trying to implement an admin area in your project ? plus your project is what a GUI a web project a command line tool ? give us details? You have a database server ? what you have done so far ?

Comment: -1 wants us to just do his homework for him.

Comment: Hi Kevin, R u the man who does home work for others. Anyway StackOverflow is the site where everyone is elligble to ask fair questions. I have posted my problem. I think none of software engineers except you do this type of home work. Please co-operate If you know the answer. One more thing In my point of view an actual software engineer never fear to any problem and never gets angry on silly questions. Please consider my last line.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question it is more about *nix passwords and logins. Have a look at the /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files and research about how the passwords are hashed. Once you understand that you may write a java program to hash the input password and compare it with the content of /etc/shadow...

Have a look at [Shadow_password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_password)

Answer (score 0):

Look at System.out.println for prompting the user and displaying the welcome message (assuming you do not have to use a GUI).  Look at Scanner(System.in) or the Console class to read the password.  Use an "if" statement to check if the password .equals the expected password (assuming it is not held in some sort of database/file).

Comment: Hi TofuBeer, I donot know admin username and password. Is there anyway that I can get this from system using jave program.